# MacOS: Chrome- Can't edit UserDataDir policy on local home computer

Tags: macos, google-chrome, preferences, plist

I am trying to edit some Chrome policies on my own Mac (non organization) which I have admin access to. For example, the 'UserDataDir' policy (https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=UserDataDir) so I can set an external hard drive location. My problem is, no matter what I do, Chrome doesn't see the changes.

I just want to make this simple change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>UserDataDir</key>
<string>/Volumes/GODZ/Misc/ChromeCanary/</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Part of the problem is when searching for how to do this, I've come across multiple answers that point to multiple different files/locations to edit so it's not even clear which is the proper one:

- Create/edit com.google.Chrome.plist file in /Library/Managed Preferences/
- Create/edit com.google.Chrome.plist file in /Library/Managed Preferences/Preferences
- Create/edit com.google.Chrome.plist file in /Library/Preferences
- Create/edit com.google.Chrome.plist file in Users/Library/Managed Preferences/
- Create/edit com.google.Chrome.plist file in Users/Library/Managed Preferences/Preferences
- Create/edit com.google.Chrome.plist file in User/Library/Preferences
- Edit com.google.Chrome.manifest in /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Resources/com.google.Chrome.manifest/Contents/Resources/

Could someone please tell me which is the proper file/location and what I need to change to do this?

Comment: I’m assuming the directory has already been created and it has all the permissions needed?

Comment: Yes, I have been using it and running a profile from it via a script that redirects to it right now, but the script has issues and has problems with Little Snitch always flagging Chrome when an update happens. That's why I want to just set the userdatadirectory directly in Chrome and avoid that.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://superuser.com/questions/1738226/macos-chrome-cant-edit-userdatadir-policy-on-local-home-computer